# Inverse of $UAA^TU^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $U\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $n<m$ be a matrix with orthogonal rows, $UU^T=I$, and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$, $m<k$ be any general real matrix.
What can I say on $(UAA^TU^T)^{-1}$ as a function of $U$ and $A$?

Comment: Note that in general $(XY)^{-1} = Y^{-1}X^{-1}$.

Comment: Orthogonal (Orthonormal matrices in your post) have to be square. You could've used $(XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$ but that only holds when both $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve edited the question. The matrix $U$ is not square.

Comment: is there a specific property of $(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{U}^\top)^{-1}$ that you're interested in? For example, it's determinant, or its action on an arbitrary vector? Or do you literally need the matrix?

Comment: @JohnMadden I have two matrices $M_1 = UAA^TU^T$ and $M_2 = VAA^TV^T$, where $UU^T=VV^T=I$, and I want to get an inequality in the spirit of $\|M_1^{-1}-M_2^{-1}\|_F^2\leq \|(U-V)(AA^T)^{-1}(U-V)^T\|_F^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $$(UAA^TU^T)^n=U(AA^T)^nU^T,$$ so
$$(UAA^TU^T)^{-1}=U(AA^T)^{-1}U^T,$$

Comment: Since $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$ with $m<k$, can you expand on what you mean by $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$?

Comment: (1/2) @JohnMadden Edited, thanks. $A^{-1}$ of a non-square matrix technically doesn't have a single definition, but say you had the non-square matrix $A$; you could use block matrices, not in the usual sense but in the sense that the

Comment: (2/2) @JohnMadden elements of the matrix are matrices themselves. This is a weird scenario since it isn't usually used, and also, isn't typically formalized or studied. But it's one whack way to have an inverse of a non-square matrix :)

Comment: @AlexanderConrad is this true when $U$ is not square? And specifically when it has less rows than columns? I know this is true for unitary, but here I have different dimensions

Comment: @JohnMadden The expression $(UAA^TU^T)^n= U(AA^T)^nU^T $ is true in this context regardless, since $UU^T=I$.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad maybe you meant to tag user in that reply?

Comment: @AlexanderConrad I don't see why, it seems one needs $U^TU=I$ in order for $(UAA^TU^T)^n=U(AA^T)^nU^T$ to be true, and we have $UU^T=I$.

Comment: @user3350919 $UU^T=(U^TU)^T=I^T=I$ :)